# decoding json string to a specified string

Tags: php, arrays

I was working on showing the week days in my website. From the admin panel, user is allowed to select the days the store will open and a general timings, and special timings.
After saving the required data, my JSON decoded object looks something like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Mon] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Mon
        )

    [Tue] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Tue
        )

    [Wed] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Wed
        )

    [Fri] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Fri
            [SPECIAL_START_TIME] => 08:00 am
            [SPECIAL_END_TIME] => 07:00 pm
        )

    [Sat] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Sat
            [SPECIAL_START_TIME] => 03:00 am
            [SPECIAL_END_TIME] => 02:00 am
        )

)
```

I have written a function, where I can get first open day of the week and last open day of the week. 
Now, the problem arises when supposing, the days open are: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Sunday. 
In this case, the first open day of the week is Monday and last open day of the week is Sunday. 
So, is there anyway I can get the first open day as Sunday and last open day as Wednesday??
There are lot of cases with this logic, struggling to get one.

Comment: That's not an array, and there is no JSON in this post...please consider an edit to the title such that it relates to what you're actually asking.

Comment: Your question is still unclear.  Are the days in your stdClass array the days that the store is open?  Or is it only open during "special time"?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your idea of a week starts on Sunday.  (Sunday - Saturday)

You should switch to storing your day of the week numerically.  Based on your preferred first day.  0 being Sunday - 6 being Saturday.

You can then use the PHP Date function and get and use

```
$dayofweek=date("w",strtotime($your_date_here));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Then you could do simple ORDER BY your day of week and get them in the same order every time.  Your example would change to.

```
 stdClass Object
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Mon
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Tue
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Wed
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Fri
            [SPECIAL_START_TIME] => 08:00 am
            [SPECIAL_END_TIME] => 07:00 pm
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Sat
            [SPECIAL_START_TIME] => 03:00 am
            [SPECIAL_END_TIME] => 02:00 am
        )

)
```

Comment: I don't have to deal with dates. I just have to show what days a store is open

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the order in which you want to process the day based data. Like,

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Mon] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_POSITION] => 1
            [DAY_NAME] => Mon
        )

    [Tue] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_POSITION] => 2
            [DAY_NAME] => Tue
        )

    [Wed] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_POSITION] => 3
            [DAY_NAME] => Wed
        )

    [Fri] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_POSITION] => 5
            [DAY_NAME] => Fri
            [SPECIAL_START_TIME] => 08:00 am
            [SPECIAL_END_TIME] => 07:00 pm
        )

    [Sat] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_POSITION] => 6
            [DAY_NAME] => Sat
            [SPECIAL_START_TIME] => 03:00 am
            [SPECIAL_END_TIME] => 02:00 am
        )

)
```

Comment: As in your question, you have a function which processes the received data. So when you do that map the data based on the value you receive in the **DAY_POSITION**. Also create an array for days and their positions as **array('0'=>'sunday', '1'=>'monday',...);** to help mapping during processing.